# Orchard 1.9.1 Container Layout

Tags: orchardcms, projection, orchardcms-1.9

I set up the following Content Definition in an Orchard 1.9.1 site:

```
Manufacturer
  - Logo (Media Library Picker Field)
  - Container (single supported type - Product)

Product
  - Containable
  - [Generic Fields]
```

I added a few sample `Product` items to the site, and as part of that it had me select the `Member Of` option, which was a list of `Manufacturer` items I had already added.

The issue I have is, when I try to build a query to use with a projection widget, I can't seem to find a way to get either a `Manufacturer`'s children, or a `Product`'s parent container since I need to display all content on a single view. There are only going to be ~20 line items here, so performance is a non-issue. If I do multiple queries (one for each type), everything shows up individually but the Shape Tracing tool, when showing me the various `Model` items on the view, can't seem to show me either of these options.

My end goal is building a custom view to display this information, but I can't figure out how to traverse either up the `Product` to what its' parent container is, or traverse down from a `Manufacturer` to the child `Product` items below it.

How do I build a query that lets me see all of this so I can build a projection widget off of that?

**Edit**

I played with this some more and came across the ability to take a query and attach a layout to it. That is definitely getting me closer, however the grouping option says `No properties are currently available in order to group this view`, however I would think being part of a container/containable would define grouping automatically. As it stands, this lets me show everything, but unfortunately the parent/child show, and then the children repeat again, independent of the parent. It's so close, but I can't quite get it right.

Comment: What exactly are you querying, products or manufacturers? If you want to show a list of manufacturers along with all their products in sub-lists, you could try changing the query layout's display type to "Detail". That seems like a simple way to get it to load and display contained items... Don't know if it's efficient, though.

Comment: Efficiency wasn't a big concern since I knew the list would be small overall, but Detail still duplicated everything as well. I was trying to show manufacturers and products (well, get everything and then package it into a custom class to control the display). I ended up switching over to an enumeration field to control manufacturers which made controlling it all much easier.